# How to use InputStream data type in RAML

Tags: java, cxf, raml, raml-java-parser

How to use InputStream data type as part of post request in  RAML.
And how to use Apache CXF MultipartBody in RAML post api

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you already tried?

Comment: Due some privacy I can't put the code. Sorry for that. 
Ex : As part of  rest API request below Employee object along with InputStream as to be received.

Class Employee has InputStream

public class Employee {
  private InputStream documentStream;
  private String identifier;
  // Setter and getter method

}

I have post above Employee object as post part of request.
How to do the request mapping/API  request setup in RAML.
Do the needful.